# What's the difference between --general-numeric-sort and --numeric-sort options in gnu sort

Tags: unix, sorting

`sort` provides two kinds of numeric sort. This is from the man page:

```
   -g, --general-numeric-sort
          compare according to general numerical value

   -n, --numeric-sort
          compare according to string numerical value
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Note that the full documentation of `sort` isn't the `man` page but the `info` page (`info sort`).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

General numeric sort compares the numbers as floats, this allows scientific notation eg 1.234E10 but is slower and subject to rounding error  (1.2345678 could come after 1.2345679), numeric sort is just a regular alphabetic sort that knows 10 comes after 9.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html

> ‘-g’ ‘--general-numeric-sort’
>   ‘--sort=general-numeric’ Sort
>   numerically, using the standard C
>   function strtod to convert a prefix of
>   each line to a double-precision
>   floating point number. This allows
>   floating point numbers to be specified
>   in scientific notation, like 1.0e-34
>   and 10e100. The LC_NUMERIC locale
>   determines the decimal-point
>   character. Do not report overflow,
>   underflow, or conversion errors. Use
>   the following collating sequence: 
>   Lines that do not start with numbers
>   (all considered to be equal).  NaNs
>   (“Not a Number” values, in IEEE
>   floating point arithmetic) in a
>   consistent but machine-dependent
>   order.  Minus infinity.  Finite
>   numbers in ascending numeric order
>   (with -0 and +0 equal).  Plus
>   infinity.
>
> Use this option only if there is no
>   alternative; it is much slower than
>   --numeric-sort (-n) and it can lose information when converting to
>   floating point.
>
> ‘-n’ ‘--numeric-sort’ ‘--sort=numeric’
>   Sort numerically. The number begins
>   each line and consists of optional
>   blanks, an optional ‘-’ sign, and zero
>   or more digits possibly separated by
>   thousands separators, optionally
>   followed by a decimal-point character
>   and zero or more digits. An empty
>   number is treated as ‘0’. The
>   LC_NUMERIC locale specifies the
>   decimal-point character and thousands
>   separator. By default a blank is a
>   space or a tab, but the LC_CTYPE
>   locale can change this.
>
> Comparison is exact; there is no
>   rounding error.
>
> Neither a leading ‘+’ nor exponential
>   notation is recognized. To compare
>   such strings numerically, use the
>   --general-numeric-sort (-g) option.

Comment: Thanks. Strange that the man and info pages don't have this in them. I also didn't know about http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html.

Comment: This stuff isn't working for me. I am sorting a file with a third column with contents like R1 R2 R10 R15.  Using either `-k3.2n` or `-k3.2g`, it is sorting `R10` before `R2`. The sort is lexicographic, not numeric. I expect it to treat the field from the second character onward as a number.

Comment: @Kaz: `sort`'s key specs. are truly byzantine - the short of it is: the *blank(s) preceding the field* are considered *part of the field*, so char. index 1 points to the (first) blank preceding the field, not the field's actual first char. Suffix the char. index with `b` to fix this problem, i.e.: `-k 3.2bn,3` (note that the _global_ `-b` option does _not_ work in this case). Also note the added `,3`, which ensures that only the 3rd field is used - without that 2nd field index, the *remainder of the entire line* is used.

Answer (score 12):

You should be careful with your locale. For example, you might intend to sort a floating number (like 2.2) whereas your locale might expect the use of a comma (like 2,2).

As reported in [this forum](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/136427-how-sort-floating-numbers-using-sort-command.html), you may have wrong results using the -n or -g flags.

In my case I use:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -k 6,6n file
```

in order to sort the 6th column that contains:

```
2.5
3.7
1.4
```

in order to obtain

```
1.4
2.5
3.7
```

Comment: Even with LANG=C, I can’t get `-n` to recognize comma as a thousands separator – “1,000” is treated the same as “1”.

Comment: That should be LC_ALL=C.

Comment: @Scott: Indeed, thousands separators are NOT recognized: `sort` uses _longest-prefix_ logic: the longest part of the line / key it recognizes as a number is used; in a locale that uses `.` as the radix character, it'll stop reading at `,`.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley: `LC_ALL=C` is indeed the _most robust_ choice; however, if `LC_ALL` happens not to bet set, `LANG=C` will work too.

Comment: Good point, but `LANG=C sort -k 6,6n file` is both simpler and also _localizes_ the effect of setting environment variable `LANG` to the specific command.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer which mention **`-g` allow scientific notation**, I want to shows the part which most likely causes undesirable behavior.

With `-g`:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 sort -g myfile
baa
--inf
--inf  
--inf- 
--inf--
--inf-a
--nnf
nnf--
   nnn  
tnan
zoo
   naN
Nana
nani lol
-inf
-inf--
-11
-2
-1
1
+1
2
+2
0xa
11
+11
inf
```

Look at the `zoo`, three important things here:

- Line starts with `NAN`(e.g. `Nana` and `nani lol`) or `-INF`(single dash, not `--INF`) move to end but before digits.
  While `INF` move to the last after digits because [it means
  infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628637/1074998).
- The `NAN`, `INF`, and `-INF` are **case insensitive**.
- The lines **always ignore whitespace from either side of `NAN`, `INF`,  `-INF`** (regardless of `LC_CTYPE`). Other alphabetic may ignore whitespace from either side depends on locale `LC_COLLATE` (e.g. `LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8` ignore but `LC_COLLATE=us_EN.UTF-8` not ignore).

So if you are sorting **arbitrary alphanumeric** then you probably don't want `-g`. If you really need scientific notation comparison with `-g`, then you probably want to extract alphabet and
   numeric data and **do comparison separately**.

If you only need ordinary number(e.g. `1, -1`) sorting, and feel that `0x/E/+ sorting` not important, just use `-n` enough:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 sort -n myfile
-1000
-22
-13
-11
-010
-10
-5
-2
-1
-0.2
-0.12
-0.11
-0.1
0x1
0x11
0xb
+1
+11
+2
-a
-aa
--aa
-aaa
-b
baa
BAA
bbb
+ignore
inf
-inf
--inf
--inf  
--inf- 
--inf--
-inf--
--inf-a
   naN
Nana
nani lol
--nnf
nnf--
   nnn  
None         
uum
Zero cool
-zzz
1
1.1
1.234E10
5
11
```

Either of `-g` or `-n`, be aware of **locale effect**. You may want to specify `LC_NUMERIC` as `us_EN.UTF-8` [to avoid fr_FR.UTF-8 sort `-` with floating number failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19985824/1074998):

```
$ LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8 sort -n myfile
-10
-5
-2
-1
-1.1
-1.2
-0.1
-0.11
-0.12
-0.2
-a
+b
middle
-wwe
+zoo
1
1.1
```

With `LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8`:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 sort -n myfile
-10
-5
-2
-1.2
-1.1
-1
-0.2
-0.12
-0.11
-0.1
-a
+b
middle
-wwe
+zoo
1
1.1
```

Or `LC_NUMERIC=us_EN.UTF-8` to group `+|-|space` with `alpha`:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=us_EN.UTF-8 sort -n myfile
-0.1
    a
    b
 a
 b
+b
+zoo
-a
-wwe
middle
1
```

You probably want to specify `locale` when using `sort` if want to write portable script.