# How can i reorder a file by ascending order (column)?

Tags: awk

I would like to reorder a whole file by ascending time order.

file.txt looks like this:

```
a 12.24 text

a 1.45 text

b 5.12 text
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
a 1.45 text

b 5.12 text

a 12.24 text
```

Comment: Why use awk when you can use Python? Also, is this a 24 hr format?

Comment: Try this one-liner in Python 2.6: open(r'temp2.txt', 'w').writelines(sorted(open(r'temp.txt', 'r').readlines(), key = lambda line: float(line.split()[1])))

Answer (score 15):

The `sort` command may fit your needs better than `awk`.

```
# sort -gk 2 test.txt 
a 1.45 text
b 5.12 text
a 12.24 text
```

**-g** compares them as numbers instead of strings. And **-k 2** sorts on the second column.

Comment: If two rows can have the same time, `-k2` will fall back on comparing entire lines to sort them. Adding a `-s` would turn this quirk off.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `sort` linux programme, not `awk`. Precisely:

```
sort -n -k 2 <filename>
```

Comment: To clarify, the difference between -n and -g is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255782/whats-the-difference-between-general-numeric-sort-and-numeric-sort-options-i .