# How to set the order of for loops

Tags: awk, gawk

I do,

```
$ awk '{ a[$0] } END{for (i in a)print i }' <(echo -e "bar\nfoo")
foo
bar
```

I also tried other input files, and the order in which these for loops run seems like random.

How do you say to awk: remain the order as in the file, so here it should be,

```
bar
foo
```

Thanks,

Eric J.

Comment: Look here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113057/how-can-i-reorder-a-file-by-ascending-order-column

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep track of the order yourself.  In this case, this is as simple as:

```
awk '{a[NR] = $0} END { for( i=1; i<= NR; i++ ) print a[i]}'
```

The arrays in awk are associative, so the index into the array can be an arbitrary string.  As such, there is no natural order on the index, so the `(i in a)` syntax returns the indices in the order determined by the implementation.  That is, the language does not impose a requirement on the order, and the implementation uses whatever data structure it wants to store the data and walks that data structure in whatever fashion is most convenient.  So different versions of awk will likely give a different order.  The order is not random, but cannot be easily predicted without understanding the underlying implementation.  By using integers for the index, you can control the order.

Answer (score 1):

See @WilliamPursell's answer for this specific case but also see the GNU awk manual (http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal) for how to set the order of evaluation of the `in` operator in general.