# Using sort in linux, how can I make 12 after 2?

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a file, leading with numbers:

```
$ cat file
1
3
13
2
4
12
```

When I use `cat file | sort`, it displays like this:

```
$ cat file | sort

1
12
13
2
3
4
```

How can I get the answer like this:

```
1
2
3
4
12
13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-n` option to enable numerical sorting:

```
$ cat file | sort -n
```

This is faster and more portable than `-g`, which is a proprietary extension of GNU `sort`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-g` option of `sort` for general sorting of numbers (can be slow for large inputs):

```
$ sort -g file
```

or:

```
$ sort -n file
```

The difference can be found in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255782/whats-the-difference-between-general-numeric-sort-and-numeric-sort-options).

**UPD:** Fixed the useless `cat` as stated in comments.

Comment: Simply use `sort -n file`. There is no need to use `cat` or stdin.

Comment: Check out the [useless use of cat award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: OP asked the question using `cat`. Yes, that use of `cat` may be useless; but, we don't know the larger context. So we don't really know, and it doesn't even matter. Whether we use a pipe or open the file with `sort` is orthogonal to the question.