# What is inf and nan?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just a question that I'm kind of confused about

So I was messing around with `float('inf')` and kind of wondering what it is used for.

Also I noticed that if I add `-inf + inf` i get `nan` is that the same as Zero or not.

I'm confused about what the uses of these two values are.

Also when I do `nan - inf` I don't get `-inf` I get `nan` I'm sure it's all pretty simple but I stumbled upon them and didn't know what they do.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`inf` is infinity - a value that is greater than any other value. `-inf` is therefore smaller than any other value.

`nan` stands for Not A Number, and this is not equal to `0`.

Although positive and negative infinity can be said to be symmetric about `0`, the same can be said for any value `n`, meaning that the result of adding the two yields `nan`. This idea is discussed in [this math.se question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60766).

Because `nan` is (literally) not a number, you can't do arithmetic with it, so the result of the second operation is also not a number (`nan`)

Comment: There is a tiny bit of arithmetic possible 
  `1 ** float('nan')` is 1.0 
Sadly `0 * float('nan')`  and `0 **float('nan')` are  both nan, not zero.  
Otoh, `0 ** float('inf') ` does equal 0.0, whereas `0 * float('inf')` is nan.

Answer (score 9):

`nan` means "not a number", a float value that you get if you perform a calculation whose result can't be expressed as a number. Any calculations you perform with `NaN` will also result in `NaN`.

`inf` means infinity.

For example:

```
>>> 2*float("inf")
inf
>>> -2*float("inf")
-inf
>>> float("inf")-float("inf")
nan
```

Comment: Interesting that the last one is not zero... it implies that infinity is different from itself. But that's actually true, because there are infinitely-many infinities. This is more intuitive though: `1 / float("inf") == 1 / float("-inf") == 0`

Answer (score 6):

`Inf` is infinity, it's a "bigger than all the other numbers" number. Try subtracting anything you want from it, it doesn't get any smaller. All numbers are `< Inf`. `-Inf` is similar, but smaller than everything.

`NaN` means not-a-number. If you try to do a computation that just doesn't make sense, you get `NaN`. `Inf - Inf` is one such computation. Usually `NaN` is used to just mean that some data is missing.

Answer (score 5):

You say:

> when i do `nan - inf` i dont get `-inf` i get `nan`

This is because any operation containing `NaN` as an operand would return `NaN`.

A comparison with `NaN` would return an *unordered result*.

```
>>> float('Inf') == float('Inf')
True
>>> float('NaN') == float('NaN')
False
```

Answer (score 5):

I use inf/-inf as initial values to find minimum/maximum value of a measurement. Lets say that you measure temperature with a sensor and you want to keep track of minimum/maximum temperature. The sensor might provide a valid temperature or might be broken. Pseudocode:

```
# initial value of the temperature
t = float('nan')          
# initial value of minimum temperature, so any measured temp. will be smaller
t_min = float('inf')      
# initial value of maximum temperature, so any measured temp. will be bigger
t_max = float('-inf')     
while True:
    # measure temperature, if sensor is broken t is not changed
    t = measure()     
    # find new minimum temperature
    t_min = min(t_min, t) 
    # find new maximum temperature
    t_max = max(t_max, t)
```

The above code works because inf/-inf/nan are valid for min/max operation, so there is no need to deal with exceptions.