# Unix shell script for increment the extension

Tags: bash, shell, unix, loops, while-loop

I have file  getting generated (testfile) eachtime a script is run in working directory. I have to copy that generated file to a directory (testfolder) and have it incremented by a .ext

If the script is run for first time then copy the testfile to testfolder as "testfile.0" and when run second time copy the testfile to testfolder as "testfile.1" and so on.

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh

file="testfile"
n=1

ls folder/${file}* | while read i
do
  if [ folder/${file}.${n} = ${i} ]
  then
   n=$(( $n + 1 ))
 fi
 done

 cp testfile folder/${file}.${n}
```

this is only working for first increment "folder/testfile.0"

Answer (score 2):

I won't correct your solution, since mklement0 does it well.

Here is another solution, without any loop:

```
file="testfile"
n_max=$(ls -1 "folder/${file}"* | egrep -o '[0-9]+$' | sort -rn | head -n 1)
cp "${file}" "folder/${file}.$((n_max+1))"
```

Here is the thing of the second line: first you list the files, then `egrep` extracts the digit extension, then `sort -rg` sorts them decreasingly, and last `head` catchs only the first line, i.e. the largest used index. Finally, in the third line, you add one to this max to build your new index. It is ok on my script if the list is empty.

By the way, listing a directory may be quite long, so I suggest you to store somewhere the last index you used for later use. Save it as a variable in the script, or even in a file ... it can save you also some time.

Comment: Nicely done; could you please remove the spaces around the `=` on the 2nd line? They break the command. A quibble: the `$[]` syntax for arithmetic expressions is apparently deprecated (see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith); thus, `$((n_max+1))` is the safer choice
Also: if you're dealing with string representations of integers when sorting, `-n` (`--numeric-sort`) is apparently preferable to `-g` (`--general-numeric-sort`) - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1255800/45375

Comment: @mkelement0: Thank you very much for your valuable comments, changes are done.

Comment: My pleasure. Your solution is a great alternative to the OP's approach; it prompted me to research the `$[]` construct (which I'd never seen before) and (finally, after always wondering) the difference between `sort`'s `-n` and `-g` options.

Comment: @mkelement0: In return, you pointed out the new syntax `$((...))`, so I've learned quite much about this topic thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `while` loop is executed in a *subshell* due to use of a pipe, so your modifications of `n` do not work as intended.

In general, you could use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) with `while` to avoid this problem, but in the case at hand a simple `for` loop is the right approach:

```
#!/bin/sh

file="testfile"
n=1

for i in folder/${file}*
do
  if [ folder/${file}.${n} = ${i} ]
  then
   n=$(( $n + 1 ))
 fi
done

cp testfile folder/${file}.${n}
```