# Printing out wrong output in bash

Tags: bash

Hi I am writing a program that ask the user to enter a directory, contact name and number.

What the program does is that it create a .contact file like `<contactname>.contact` and adds the contact number inside it. If the file already exists in the specified directory, then the program creates a new file called `contact(1).contact`, if that exists then `contact(2).contact` etc.

When  a `contact(1).contact` already exists, I want the program to create `contact(2).contact`, but the program creates `contact(1)(2).contact` file instead. I don't know what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated ! :)

The code I have written so far in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=
if(($# == 0))
then
 echo -n "Please enter directory path:"
 read directory 
 cd $directory


 echo -n "Please enter contact name:"
 read name

 echo -n "Please enter contact number:"
 read number

else
 directory=$1
 cd ${directory}

 name=$2
 number=$3
fi

if [ -e $name.contact ];

then
exists=1
count=1

while [ $exists -eq 1 ];
do
name=$name\($count\)
count=$(($count+1))
if [ ! -f $name.contact ];
then
exists=0

fi

done

echo $number > $name.contact
name=5
else

echo $number > $name.contact

fi
```

Comment: You can also find some hints for other ways to do the job in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974355/unix-shell-script-for-increment-the-extension/17975651#17975651)

Answer (score 4):

You keep appending to the modified name. Use the original name instead.

And that condition...

```
origname="$name"
while [ -f $name.contact ];
do
  name="$origname($count)"
  count=$(($count+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to save original name:

Try changing that part:

```
while [ $exists -eq 1 ];
do
name=$name\($count\)
count=$(($count+1))
if [ ! -f $name.contact ];
then
exists=0
fi

done
```

to this:

```
origname=$name
while [ $exists -eq 1 ];
do
name=$origname\($count\)
count=$(($count+1))
if [ ! -f $name.contact ];
then
exists=0
fi

done
```