# Negative floating point numbers are not sorted correctly using awk or sort

Tags: sorting, awk, floating-point, locale

For some reason, comparisons of negative floating point numbers with `awk` and `sort` seem to be broken on my machine. It seems that `-0.1 < -0.2`.

When I try to sort

```
0.2
-0.1
-0.2
0.1
0
```

using `sort -n test.dat`, I get

```
-0.1
-0.2
0
0.1
0.2
```

instead of

```
-0.2
-0.1
0
0.1
0.2
```

What is wrong with me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer:** You are French!

In french, the decimal point is a comma (`,`) and not a dot (`.`). You need to either replace the dots with commas or change your locale.

Try `LC_NUMERIC=us_EN.UTF-8 sort -n test.dat` and you should get the expected result.

For your information, `LC_NUMERIC` is an environment variable that contains the locale to use for formatting non-monetary numbers.

Comment: +1: lol, very good first sentence ^^ (and I am French, too ^^)