# Bash sort using general numeric value on alphanumeric string not returning rows sorted properly

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, numeric, alphanumeric

I have a file containing three TAB-separated columns. The 1st column is a number, the second is a sequence of 8 characters followed by 1-3 digits, the 3rd is the same as the 2nd column. Here's a minimum reproducible example:

```
1       abceefgh10      abceefgh22
1       abceefgh10      abceefgh9
1       abceefgh11      abceefgh10
1       abceefgh13      abceefgh11
1       abceefgh14      abceefgh13
1       abceefgh15      abceefgh14
1       abceefgh17      abceefgh16
-1      abceefgh18      abceefgh17
1       abceefgh19      abceefgh18
-1      abceefgh1       abceefgh2
-1      abceefgh20      abceefgh12
1       abceefgh21      abceefgh19
1       abceefgh22      abceefgh20
-1      abceefgh23      abceefgh21
1       abceefgh24      abceefgh24
1       abceefgh2       abceefgh1
1       abceefgh3       abceefgh3
1       abceefgh5       abceefgh5
1       abceefgh6       abceefgh25
1       abceefgh6       abceefgh6
1       abceefgh7       abceefgh7
-1      abceefgh8       abceefgh3
1       abceefgh9       abceefgh8
```

This example is what I get when I try to sort the columns with `sort -gk2.9`.

To the best of my knowledge I should expect to see the second column sorted from 1 to 24, and with increasing numerical value (i.e. 1,2,3,4,... and not 1,10,2,20,..., which would result if using `-n`).

If I cut the 2nd column and sort it with the same command (`cut -f 2 ${file} | sort -gk1.9`), I actually get the sorting that I want. Am I getting something obvious wrong?

Comment: what about `sort -t $'\t' -V -k2`, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255800/1454708) general numeric sort is for number with exponent

Comment: Thank you, it worked. As a side-note, it worked also without using the natural version sorting (`-V`), as long as I specified the field separator using `$'\t'`.

Comment: more exactly should be `sort -t $'\t' -V -k2,2` to sort only over second column otherwise sorts also over the next columns

Answer (score 3):

Using `--debug` option you can see column selection does not work as expected:

```
1>abceefgh10>abceefgh9  
         ^ no match for key
```

specifying separator in accordance with Nahuel's comment works (`sort -t $'\t' --debug -gk2.9`):

```
1>abceefgh10>abceefgh9     
          __
```

Comment: looking at the manual : `KEYDEF ... If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted from the beginning of the preceding whitespace.`

Comment: Right. Deleted "poor documentation" paragraph.